# How do i add adsense code in vbulletin archive page?

Tags: adsense, vbulletin

How do I add adsense code into vbulletin archive page?
Which method can I use?
I need to place the code in the archive index page.

Answer (score 0):

Which vBulletin version do you use? Use the template manager to edit the default archive template and insert the ad sense code.

Answer (score 0):

vBulletin 4.x contains default locations which you use to insert advertising throughout your forum in a range of predefined locations including it's archive. In addition you can also configure your own from a list of options.

To use a default location:

Admin Control Panel > Advertising > Manage Ads > Archive

and follow the prompts to configure your ad.

To configure your own:

Admin Control Panel > Advertising > Manage Ads > Ad a New Ad > Archive

and follow the prompts to configure your ad.

However note that Adsense's code will disable any links which it deems too close to it's own so you'll need to use the Below Content location in order to avoid disabling your Archive's existing navigation links.